# Calling PartialView Doesn't work on External Network

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to load a partialview from a JQuery load function
[image]

The above basically calls a Load Action from Codes Controller
[image]

This works when accessing the Web Application on an internal Network but not when it get access from the internet. Here are the steps I did on investigation:

- Enable CORS on the IIS (web.config) and on the Code (AspNetCore.Cors)
- Use JQUERY to enable CORS (using crossDomain:true)
- Enable Network Discover on the Windows Server
- I even tried putting the _Load.cshtml into the SHARED folder and calling the load directly without the path but still didn't work.

This question is linked to the question I posted but the CORS suggestion doesn't work.[My Other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215182/network-error-0x2efd-could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-00002efd)

Aside from using the load, as mentioned, I have tried using $.ajax and output the error but I'm getting

```
readystate 0 status 0 statustext error ajax
```

Many thanks in advance.

------------------UPDATE----------------------

This is calling the URL directly as mentioned

[image]

------------------UPDATE 2----------------------

When calling from $.ajax, I put e.preventDefault();

[image]

Error showing in Chrome

[image]

Error Showing in IE[image]

Comment: Is your calling page (in which you have written jquery code for ajax) and the Action method URL (your baseURL variable) are in same domain? If both are in same domain then you do not need to worry about CORS. What happens when you directly visit that URL (baseURL + /Codes/Load?id=xxxxx) from your browser instead of ajax? does it give error?

Comment: @Kiran, yes, they are both in the same domain. When I run the url directly, I can see the correct result without css format. That works for both internal and external network.

Comment: You do not need to use baseUrl at all since both are in same domain. You can use **.load("/Code/Load?id=.....");** directly. Also can you make sure #cmbGroup change event is not initiating postback (or redirect to other URL) right after the ajax call?

Comment: @Kiran, when I don't use the baseURL variable it doesn't work because of the Virtual Directory.

Comment: Please share screenshot of dev toolbar when it is called from javascript

Comment: @Kiran, Updated with screenshots on Chrome and IE

Comment: You may need to compare the difference in requests made by ajax and made directly in browser in fiddler. also there are similar error related questions I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868673/edge-on-windows-10-32-bit-blocking-ajax-call-to-localhost-with-network-error-0x2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176300/winjs-xhr-network-error-0x2efd-could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kiran for the help. I figured out the issue.

the URL from outside has port number in it. the problem is that when it calls the Control and the Action, the URL doesn't include the port number. The code now includes the port number but have to hard code it. I have tried using

```
@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port
```

But it keeps on showing 80 rather than the actual port.

[image]